# Apply df.where to selective columns in pandas to remove outliers in mixed data type dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outliers

Python and pandas newbie setting up a data cleaning pipeline to prep df for machine learning. I would like to identify and remove outliers and substitute in place (for example) the arithmetic mean.

The df has been cleaned so that column #1 of strings ('Identifiers') was set as the index (type=object) and the rest of the columns are purely numeric and set as float. Toy deindentified version of input df:

> ```
> Identifiers        foo  categorical   bar  score1  score2  score3
> 0         bob   9.717501          1.0   2.0    34.0     4.0    44.0
> 1       carol  15.940285          0.0   6.0    65.0     3.0    46.0
> 2       alice  13.938485          0.0  32.0    55.0    18.0    68.0
> 3         jim   8.918572          0.0  15.0    71.0     5.0    50.0
> 4      nathan   9.698413          0.0   4.0    36.0    10.0    48.0
> ```

The following code runs successfully:

```
for col in df_pheno:
s = df_pheno.mean(axis = 0)
q = df_pheno.std (axis = 0)
r = s + (3 * q)
if col == 'Identifiers':
    continue
elif col != 'Identifiers':
    for i, row_value in df_pheno[col].iteritems():
        if row_value > r.loc[col]:
            row_value = df_pheno.replace(row_value,s.loc[col],inplace = True)
        elif row_value <= r.loc[col]:
            continue
```

Output (note: in the toy example the condition was changed from r to s but otherwise nothing is different):

> ```
> Identifiers        foo  categorical   bar  score1  score2  score3
> 0         bob   9.717501          0.2   2.0    34.0     4.0    44.0
> 1       carol  11.642651          0.0   6.0    52.2     3.0    46.0
> 2       alice  11.642651          0.0  11.8    52.2     8.0    51.2
> 3         jim   8.918572          0.0  11.8    52.2     5.0    50.0
> 4      nathan   9.698413          0.0   4.0    36.0     8.0    48.0
> ```

I would like to see if df.where speeds up the operation, but in various permutations I either a) can't get it to ignore the 'Identifiers' column or b) input a non-NaN value. For reasons to do with the next step in the pipeline I would prefer not to insert NaN and then input the non-NaN values -- if this is possible. Example efforts/problems:

```
for col in df_pheno:
s = df_pheno.mean(axis = 0)
q = df_pheno.std (axis = 0)
r = s + (3 * q)
if col == 'Identifiers':
    continue
elif col != 'Identifiers':
    df_pheno.where(df_pheno > r, s, inplace=True, axis=1)
```

TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value

And alternatively:

```
for col in df_pheno:
s = df_pheno.mean(axis = 0)
q = df_pheno.std (axis = 0)
r = s + (3 * q)
if col == 'Identifiers':
    continue
elif col != 'Identifiers':
    df_pheno[col].where(df_pheno[col] > r, s[col], inplace=True, axis=1)
```

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, could you show an example of your input and output data frame?

Comment: Thanks - Long time reader, first time poster. I have edited the question to include a toy example of input and successful output.

Comment: I don't understand why there are values ​​equal to 0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because the series of std (`s`), mean  and `r` do not have a value for Identifiers, however the DataFrame does. That's why I'm going to use `set_index('Identifiers')` and when I finish operating `reset_index()`.

Consult here:

[DataFrame.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) y [DataFrame.reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

---

I think you only need:

```
df=df_pheno.set_index('Identifiers')
m=df.mean()
s=df.std()
r=m+3*s
```

---

Now apply [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with **r** , **m** or **s**:

```
df.mask(df>m,m,axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Identifiers        foo  categorical  bar  score1  score2  score3
0         bob  10.723134          0.0  1.0    40.0     3.0    48.0
1       carol  11.567761          0.2  0.0    34.0     2.0    43.0
2       alice  11.567761          0.0  9.2    50.4     7.6    53.8
3         jim  10.793862          0.0  9.2    50.4     3.0    48.0
4      nathan   9.633013          0.0  2.0    44.0     7.6    53.8
```

---

or

```
df.mask(df>s,s,axis=1).reset_index()
```

or

```
df.mask(df>r,r,axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks very much @ansev. This works perfectly & with tiny edit to your last line works inplace. I wasn't thinking correctly about setting the index. Had done it earlier but I guess was implicitly thinking of it as applying to the global space.